# Ошибка при написании базы данных на python

Tags: python, sqlite3

Пишу базу данных для программы и при заполнении таблицы возникает следующая ошибка.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\bot_zadach\test.py", line 48, in <module>
sql_insert(con, entities)
File "F:\bot_zadach\test.py", line 44, in sql_insert
cursorObj.execute('INSERT INTO users("id", "fullname", "1za", "1za_pom", "2za", "2za_pom", "3za", 
"3za_pom", "4za" ,"4za_pom", "5za", "6za", "6za_pom", "7za", "7za_pom", 
"8za","8za_pom","9za","9za_pom","10za","10za_pom") VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', entities)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 21, and 
there are 22 supplied.
```

Количество столбцов в и количество данных, которые ввожу одинаковое

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error

def sql_connection():
    try:
        con = sqlite3.connect('mydatabase.db')
        return con
    except Error:
        print(Error)

def sql_table(con):
    cursorObj = con.cursor()
    cursorObj.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
                        "id" INT PRIMARY KEY,
                        "fullname" TEXT,
                        "1za" TEXT,
                        "1za_pom" INT,
                        "2za" TEXT,
                        "2za_pom" INT,
                        "3za" TEXT,
                        "3za_pom" INT,
                        "4za" TEXT,
                        "4za_pom" INT,
                        "5za" TEXT,
                        "5za_pom" INT,
                        "6za" TEXT,
                        "6za_pom" INT,
                        "7za" TEXT,
                        "7za_pom" INT,
                       "8za" TEXT,
                        "8za_pom" INT,
                        "9za" TEXT,
                        "9za_pom" INT,
                        "10za" TEXT,
                        "10za_pom" INT);
""")
    con.commit()

con = sql_connection()
sql_table(con)

def sql_insert(con, entities):
    cursorObj = con.cursor()
    cursorObj.execute('INSERT INTO users("id", "fullname", "1za", "1za_pom", "2za", "2za_pom", "3za",                 "3za_pom", "4za" ,"4za_pom", "5za", "6za", "6za_pom", "7za", "7za_pom", "8za","8za_pom","9za","9za_pom","10za","10za_pom") VALUES("?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', entities)
con.commit()
entities = (12, 'Andrew', '1', 1, '2', 2, '3', 3, '4', 4, '5', 5, '6', 6, '7', 7, '8', 8, '9', 9,     '10', 10)

sql_insert(con, entities)
```

Comment: Количество вопросиков и количество данных в entities явно неодинаковое, пересчитайте ещё раз внимательно

Comment: не смогли перевести сообщение об ошибке? ;)

Comment: Советую вам почитать о трех нормальных формах в теории баз данных и не строить такие модели данных в будущем